# Laravel 4.2 continue routing

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-4.2

Imagine there is the following url structure:

```
someurl.axyz/{post-slug}
someurl.axyz/{page-slug}
```

`post-slug` and `page-slug` are stored in the unique database table column. What is the "most" elegant way to handle the routes with Laravel 4.2 (and if there is a difference the way with Laravel v5.2)?

I resolved this using binding parameter to a model. The following code is at the bottom of routes.php file. I would like to know whether there is simpler solution for this task.

```
Route::bind('directslug', function($value, $route) {
    $post = Post::where('slug', $value)->first();
    if ($post) {
        return $post;
    }
    $page = Page::where('slug', $value)->first();
    if ($page) {
        return $page;
    }

    throw new NotFoundHttpException;
});
Route::get('{directslug}', function(Post $post) {
    return $post;
});
Route::get('{directslug}', function(Page $page) {
    return $page;
});

App::missing(function($exception) {
    return Response::view('error.missing', array('title' => '404 Page not Found'), 404);
});
```

Comment: For 4.2 you have to manually bind the parameter, like you've done, and 5.2 binds it out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I handle everything with [route model binding](https://laravel.com/docs/4.2/routing#route-model-binding), fairly similarly to your solution.

In my opinion you should keep a separate model for each route, otherwise you might end up with a post having the same slug of a page... even if I'm sure you've taken care of this. You use two different routes afterall, why should you **always** query for a post if someone is looking for a page?